# New Canary Channel Android Studio Release 0.8.11 Not Offering Upate

Tags: android, android-studio

The release notes say that if you are running 0.8.x, it will let you do the usual update and restart. I have 0.8.8 and it's not giving me that option.

I know this release is bringing support for Gradle 2.1 with it. Guess I will do a complete release, but I could not make a comment on the release page. At the least, the release notes should be corrected.

Comment: Ummm... what is your question?

Comment: Why the release notes are wrong and it is not letting me do Update and Restart.

Comment: Are you sure you're on canary channel?